# Error using WorkbookConnection Object to run an Insert Query

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, sql-insert

I am using VBA to refresh a Data Connection in an Excel workbook with a string variable being used for the Query to run.

When using a SELECT query this all works as it should; if it is an INSERT query, it throws an application-defined or object-defined error on `Connections(ConnectionName).Refresh`

The error does not repeat itself if I run the code to the point where it adds the Query string into the Data Connection and manually click the Refresh button in Excel.

```
Sub UploadData()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim UploadSheetNum As Integer
Dim QueryCol As String
Dim QueryString As String
Dim CurRowString As String
Dim ConnName As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
UploadSheetNum = 3
QueryCol = "H"
ConnName = "DataConn"
Call VBAModule_v1.SwitchtoSheet(UploadSheetNum, wb)
For i = 1 To VBAModule_v1.GetLastRow(QueryCol)
    CurRowString = wb.Sheets(UploadSheetNum).Range(QueryCol & i)
    QueryString = QueryString & CurRowString & Chr(10)
Next i
Call VBAModule.RefreshConnection(ConnName, QueryString, wb)
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub RefreshConnection(ConnectionName As String, Query As String, wb As Workbook)
wb.Activate
On Error GoTo ExitProc
With wb.Connections(ConnectionName).ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = Query
End With
wb.Connections(ConnectionName).Refresh
DoEvents
Exit Sub

ExitProc:
MsgBox ("Error Sub RefreshConnection: Issue with ConnectionName '" & _
  ConnectionName & "' or Query - " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually just tripped over the answer. So, WorkbookConnection Object works for queries that return a result e.g Select queries, but not so much for queries that don't e.g. Insert, Update, Deletes.

The below subroutine will run an Insert query without error:

```
Sub RunInsertQuery(InsertTable As String, InsertValues As String)

On Error GoTo ExitProc

        Dim Dataconn As Object

        Set Dataconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        connstr = "DRIVER={'SQL DRIVER To Use'};" & _
                "SERVER='SERVERNAME to Connect to';" & _
                "PORT='PortNumber'" & _
                "DATABASE='Database Name';" & _
                "UID='User Id to use';" & _
                "PWD='User Password';"

        Dataconn.Open connstr

        Dataconn.Execute "INSERT INTO " & InsertTable & " VALUES " & InsertValues

        Dataconn.Close

        Set Dataconn = Nothing

        Exit Sub

ExitProc:

MsgBox ("Error Sub RunInsertQuery: Issue with Tablename for Insert '" & InsertTable & "' or Values being Inserted - " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```